# How do I use array_map recursively in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am attempting to convert an associative array to a 2D array to allow me to export it to Google Sheets. I've figured out a simplistic solution that works as follows:

```
$headers = $data["resultSets"][0]["headers"];

$rowSet0 = $data["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"][0];
$rowSet1 = $data["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"][1];

$hackresults = array_map(null, $headers, $rowSet0, $rowSet1);
```

This produces the following:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SEASON_ID
            [1] => 22017
            [2] => 22017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player_ID
            [1] => 203954
            [2] => 203954
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Game_ID
            [1] => 0021701118
            [2] => 0021701105
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => GAME_DATE
            [1] => MAR 28, 2018
            [2] => MAR 26, 2018
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => MATCHUP
            [1] => PHI vs. NYK
            [2] => PHI vs. DEN
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => WL
            [1] => W
            [2] => W
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => MIN
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 27
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGM
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 6
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGA
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 12
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => FG_PCT
            [1] => 0.333
            [2] => 0.5
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => FG3M
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => FG3A
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => FG3_PCT
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => FTM
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 8
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => FTA
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 10
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => FT_PCT
            [1] => 0.5
            [2] => 0.8
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => OREB
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => DREB
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 12
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => REB
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 13
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => AST
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => STL
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => BLK
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOV
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => PF
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 5
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => PTS
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 20
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => PLUS_MINUS
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 20
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO_AVAILABLE
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

This is the output I'm looking for, but there are 27  "rowSet"s, and it seems there must be a recursive way of performing this task.

I've looked at a number of custom array_map_recursive style functions but haven't had any success. Apologies and thanks in advance, I am a terrible novice coder!

Comment: In future, providing the original array to compare with your output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new).

With the `...` operator, you can use all the elements under `$data["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"]` as additional arguments to `array_map`.

```
$headers = $data["resultSets"][0]["headers"];
$rowSets = $data["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"];

$results = array_map(null, $headers, ...$rowSets);
```

(This isn't recursion, but I think it does what you're trying to do.)